# In SQL Server, is it possible to include 2 columns in an IN clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, in-clause

I'm trying to use an IN clause, however the filtering needs to be on a set of items defined by 2 columns. Is this possible? There are probably other ways to do this (e.g. table variable), but I'd like to do it as an IN clause, if possible, because that would be more elegant and simpler to dynamically create in my application.

This psuedo code might make it clearer what I'm trying to do.

```
SELECT *
FROM Distributors
WHERE (City,State) IN (('Springfield','OH'), ('Springfield','MO'), ('Houston','TX'))
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: I have done this thing in the past by concatinating; but I'm not sure this is a good way: I would do something like WHERE City + '@' + State IN ('Springfield@OH', 'Springfield@MO', 'Houston@TX')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * 
from distributors
where  ( city = 'Springfield' and State = 'OH') OR
       ( city = 'Springfield' and State = 'MO') OR
       ( city = 'Houston' and State = 'TX')
```

not so complicated

Comment: Actually, I think that this could be exactly what I'm looking for. I was thinking that I needed and IN clause, but OR conditions do exactly the same work.

Comment: and by using OR clause instead of IN would result in better performance

Answer (score 5):

Easiest is probably to produce a pseudo-table and perform a join to it. Either [`VALUES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd776382%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) (SQL Server 2008 or later):

```
SELECT d.*
FROM Distributors d
JOIN (VALUES ('Springfield','OH'), ('Springfield','MO'), ('Houston','TX'))
    as t(City,State)
ON d.City = t.City and d.State = t.State
```

Or `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM Distributors d
JOIN (SELECT 'Springfield','OH' UNION ALL SELECT 'Springfield','MO' UNION ALL SELECT 'Houston','TX')
    as t(City,State)
ON d.City = t.City and d.State = t.State
```

I admit, I'm not using `IN` any more, but the separators between the varying elements are all identical (in either case), so hopefully it still hits:

> simpler to dynamically create in my application.

(Also, your attempt was not only reasonable, it's actually close to what is in the ANSI Standards - might be worth your while voting on [this connect issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/299231))

Comment: I agree.  In face, the "IN" clause is forbidden in Production code.  WHERE EXISTS or one of the tricks above...is preferred.  Upvote for alternate syntaxes.

Comment: Wow, that issue has been open since 2007. However, I got a "voting no longer enabled on this item".

Comment: @John - that's odd. I was sure there *would* *be* a connect issue, but I hadn't seen it before personally - so I've only just cast my vote on it and it was accepted without error

Comment: Damien, my bad. Voting was no longer allowed, because I had just clicked it without realizing it. D'oh.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do multiple `IN` statements, this can be achieved by:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM Distributors
 WHERE CITY IN ('SPRINGFIELD', 'HOUSTON')
 AND STATE IN ('OH', 'MO', 'TX')
```

However it seems you want to filter using `OR`

```
 SELECT *
 FROM Distributors
 WHERE (City = 'Houston' AND State = 'TX') OR
 (City = 'Springfield' AND State = 'OH') OR
 (City = 'Springfield' AND State = 'MO')
```

Comment: @John - I initally did, but corrected it before you posted the comment.

Comment: but this would also incorrectly match ('Springfield', 'TX') which he presumably did not want..

Comment: Yes, but your query also brings back Houston, OH, which I don't want.

Comment: @Minky I believe the OP wants a different type of query which does not use IN in this case.

Comment: @John - check my update.  I have included how you can achieve this.

Comment: Darren, I think MLeblanc actually beat you with the same query 5 minutes ago =)

Comment: @John - McLeblanc's answer is also correct but it's not a race. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer, not pretty but it works:

```
SELECT *
FROM Distributors d
  INNER JOIN (SELECT 
                'Springfield' AS city
                ,'OH' AS state
              UNION 
              SELECT
                'Springfield'
                ,'MO'
              UNION
              SELECT 
                'Houston'
                ,'TX') x
WHERE d.city = x.city
  AND d.state = x.State
```

Answer (score 0):

This construct is not supported. However you could write this in a slightly different way to the other suggestions:

```
SELECT <column list>
FROM dbo.Distributors
WHERE (City = 'Springfield' AND State IN ('OH', 'MO'))
   OR (City = 'Houston' AND State = 'TX');
```